# Elegant way to create a list of equally spaced arrays

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I have a vector r0 defined via `r0 = np.r_[0, 0, 1]`.

I can define its mirror image  `r0 = -r0`, which is `np.r_[0, 0, -1]`.

I would like to create a list of `r0`, like this:

```
0, 0, -1
0, 0, -1 + step
0, 0, -1 + 2*step
...
0, 0, 1
```

as an array of 3 columns and (1-(-1))/step lines.

I can only think of doing this with a list and then turning it into an array, but I'd really like to keep working with arrays since I converted all my code to vectors.

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: an array of 3 columns and (1-(-1))/step lines.

Comment: You appear to be using Numpy. You really should add the `numpy` tag to such questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to be looking for `np.linspace`:

```
>>> z_start = -1
>>> z_stop = 1
>>> step = 0.25
>>> np.linspace(z_start, z_stop, num=1+(z_stop-z_start)/step)
array([-1.  , -0.75, -0.5 , -0.25,  0.  ,  0.25,  0.5 ,  0.75,  1.  ])
```

Packing them back into an array:

```
>>> z = np.linspace(z_start, z_stop, num=1+(z_stop-z_start)/step)
>>> n = len(z)
>>> np.vstack([np.zeros(n), np.zeros(n), z]).T
array([[ 0.  ,  0.  , -1.  ],
       [ 0.  ,  0.  , -0.75],
       [ 0.  ,  0.  , -0.5 ],
       [ 0.  ,  0.  , -0.25],
       [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ],
       [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.25],
       [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.5 ],
       [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.75],
       [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  1.  ]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create one numpy array and have a list of views for parts of the data.

```
import numpy as np

step = 10
r = np.zeros((step, 3))
r[:, -1] = np.linspace(-1, 1, step)

r0 = [r[i] for i in range(r.shape[0])]

# r0 == [array([ 0.,  0., -1.]),
#  array([ 0.,  0., -0.77777778]),
#  array([ 0.,  0., -0.55555556]),
#  array([ 0.,  0., -0.33333333]),
#  array([ 0.,  0., -0.11111111]),
#  array([ 0.,  0.,  0.11111111]),
#  array([ 0.,  0.,  0.33333333]),
#  array([ 0.,  0.,  0.55555556]),
#  array([ 0.,  0.,  0.77777778]),
#  array([ 0.,  0.,  1.])]
```